# string handling in ruby makes my work stop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are many names in my Role collections. Here I want to bring my all names in from Role collections.

```
 <% @all= Role.all %>
    <% @all.each do |all|%>
    <%= all.name%>
    <% end %>
```

This gives the format in  Admin Ram Manager Prem
But i want my output in ["Admin", "Ram", "Manager", "Prem"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= Role.all.collect(&:name) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this...

```
[<%= '"' + @roles.collect {|r| r.name}.join('", "') + '"' %>]
```

And I would assign @roles in your Controller...

Doing it in this way will separate "what you select as roles" from "how you display the roles", which makes it easier to test.

And if you need to ensure no newline breaks, [set the css white-space to nowrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) (using nbsp gets a bit unwieldy to handle).